# jQuery function not responding

Tags: html, click

I wrote a simple html file to test buttons which call alert() when clicked, but I see no response at all. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong? It's so weird.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signupstyle.css"> -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            alert("button");
            console.log("button");
        });  

        $("#facebook").click(function(){
            alert("button");
            console.log("button");
        });    


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
    <button id="facebook">Sign up with Facebook</button>

</body>
```

Comment: ... or place at the `<body>`'s end.

Comment: Just to note **place script before the closing '</body>` tag!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add document.ready function and write all your events in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });  

    $("#facebook").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });    
});
```

or do like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });  

    $("#facebook").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap all your jquery selectors within a document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });  

    $("#facebook").click(function(){
        alert("button");
        console.log("button");
    });    
});
```

There are other methods but htis should work.

Comment: @ueg1990 yea just add it in the head. Better practise that way

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap you code in $(document).ready(function(){your code goes here})

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to run the script before the DOM is loaded, one different option from the other answers is to execute your script after your DOM elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signupstyle.css"> -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>
    <button id="facebook">Sign up with Facebook</button>
      <script>

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            alert("button");
            console.log("button");
        });  

        $("#facebook").click(function(){
            alert("button");
            console.log("button");
        });    


</script>
</body>
```